# Git config: list only the effective values

Tags: git

Some git config values are configured at the system, some at the user level and some in the repository. When invoking

```
$ git config --list
```

I'm getting a list of all definitions in all files. Overridden values will occur duplicated. How to get a list of the repository's **effective** values (I don't care about where they are configured)?

Comment: Have a look at --show-origin... l think local is prefered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tricky part is this:

> Overridden values will occur duplicated.

It's true that some items, e.g., `user.name` and `user.email`, will have a more-local value override a more-global value.  For other items, though, *all* the settings apply.  This is true for `remote.*.fetch` values, for instance.

The actual treatment of any one item *depends on the program that examines the setting*.  The `git config` command does not know how a `git xyzzy` command—which is not yet written (it's something you will write some time in the future)—intends to use all the `xyzzy.*` settings.  So it just shows all of them.  Use `--show-origin` to show which particular configuration file was the source of any one particular setting.

If you're interested in one *particular* value, use `git config --get`:

```
git config --get core.editor
```

or:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

The `--get` variant shows the *last* setting, i.e., the most-local one, while the `--get-all` variant shows *all* the settings.  Which one to use depends, of course, on how the program you will run—which might be one already written, or might be one you're in the process of writing now or will write next year—actually uses that variable.

One could argue that `git config` should understand all the "well known" variable names (`core.editor` vs `remote.*.fetch` for instance) and default to showing them appropriately under `--list`.  The Git authors tend to treat Git as a tool-set rather than a solution, though, so they are not very receptive to this line of argument.

*You* can write this smarter version of `git config --list` yourself.  Perhaps you can call it `git xyzzy`. :-)  OK, maybe `git smart-config-list`.  Your smarter listing command will run `git config --show-origins --list`, then apply the "all or last" filtering rule based on its knowledge about all those variable names.  As you write this command, think about Git's "tools vs solutions" philosophy, and that `git config` is not that well designed since it acts as both plumbing (internal-usage tool) *and* porcelain (an end-user-facing command).

Comment: Could you please describe in what case overridden values are used?

Comment: If they're used, they're not overridden: they're cumulative. The only really glaring case for this is `remote.*.fetch`. Once you set `remote.origin.fetch` to `a:a` and then also to `b:b`, running `git fetch origin` with no refspecs is equivalent to running `git fetch origin a:a b:b`. All the accumulated `remote.origin.fetch` settings apply. I don't know offhand of any other examples, but there probably are some, if not in main Git then in someone's personal commands.

Answer (score 1):

Make a bash function:

```
function foo(){
    para=$@
    for key in `git config --list ${para}| awk -F= '{print $1}' | sort -u`;do
        echo $key=`git config ${para} --get $key`
    done
}
```

`foo` to get a list of the repository's effective values. `foo --global`, `foo --local`, `foo --system`, `foo -f somefile` or `foo --blob someblob` are also supported.